# Parking for 3 - 4 days in Vancouver, BC

Tags: automobiles, vancouver

I'm moving from Alaska to Portland and will be driving to make the move. Along the way I wanted to stop in Vancouver and check out the city for 3-4 days. I will have all my stuff in the car so i'm looking to find a secure place to park the car that is reasonably priced. I will have my bike with me for travel within the city and can use public transportation as well. I don't have to park the car downtown but close as possible would be good.

Everywhere I've looked online is either for monthly parking or day use only, nothing about overnight. Any locals or fellow travelers know a few tips that could help with this situation?

Answer (score 3):

If you are staying in a hotel, you might want to get in touch with them and see if they have parking and how secure it is. Many hotels have their own lots, and if they are only available to guests, then you would assume that they are more secure than your average city parking.

Even if your hotel doesn't have its own parking, they can probably recommend a location which is close by and meets your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I should have mentioned that I'm  staying at a hostel and none I've seen include parking.

Comment: They might still have suggestions for you.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you're staying and how close is 'near' to downtown.  However, [this website - Parkopedia](http://en.parkopedia.ca/free/vancouver/parking/), shows you where the parking places are in Vancouver, and some are either free or $1/hour, and several are available 24 hours a day.